# Is it possible to block extension executeScript? Issue with running simple alert

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am developing a browser extension for Chrome and Firefox, and a few websites seem to somehow be able to prevent `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` from working properly. Based on my research, this doesn't seem possible, but maybe someone can indicate a trick certain websites can use?

I have developed a simplistic example that reproduces the error.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "author": "Test",
  "description": "",

  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "history",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test"
  },

  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```js
window.chrome = (function() {
  return window.msBrowser || window.browser || window.chrome;
})();

function doAlert() {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'https://twitter.com',
    active: true
  }, (tab) => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
      code: 'alert("test")'
    });
  });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  doAlert();
});
```

In general, I expect that a tab will open and load twitter.com, then show the alert.

In Chrome, as soon as the tab loads, I get the error "the tab was closed" as it tries to run `executeScript`.
In Firefox, it *looks* like the alert might happen before the website loads, but it happens so fast I can't really tell. There's no error logged to the background script console.

Most other URLs work just fine, popping up the alert as expected (I've confirmed it working on this site, Google, Facebook, etc). LinkedIn is another example where it doesn't work.

Comment: In Firefox, you are not using `chrome.tabs.create()` You explicitly overwrite that to be equivalent to [`browser.tabs.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create), which is promise based, not callback based. Thus, the callback you pass is ignored. You should just use `chrome.tabs.create()` without overwriting `chrome` with `browser`. Frankly, your `window.chrome = ` line just makes it harder/impossible for you to write code that is compatible across browsers.

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/820080. The workaround is to additionally use chrome.tabs.onUpdated.

Comment: @Makyen you are right, in regards to FF usage. I'll have to look into `window.msBrowser` for Edge support again and see if it's still helpful. (This stuff was copied from an older attempt.)

Comment: @wOxxOm that looks like the same issue. I'll try out `onUpdated` and see if it can help.